# redirect qDebug to QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use `qInstallMessageHandler(handler)` to redirect the `qDebug` to `QTextEdit`.

I define a handler function in a class:

```
void Spider::redirect(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext& context, const QString& msg)
{
    console->append(msg);
}
```

and call `qInstallMessageHandler(redirect)` in the constructor of the class (Spider).

But, when i compile this program, i got a error:

> cannot convert 'Spider::redirect' from type 'void
>   (Spider::)(QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext&, const QString&)' to
>   type 'QtMessageHandler {aka void (*)(QtMsgType, const
>   QMessageLogContext&, const QString&)}'

If i define the handler function in global, it's ok.

I can't figure out the difference between these two behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-static class method and a global function have different signatures. You cannot use a non-static method as a function.

Comment: Downvoting because this does not answer the question of "how to redirect qDebug to QTextEdit." This answer explains *why the asker got the error* not *how to solve the asker's problem*.

Answer (score 12):

I really like having this debugging ability around.  I've done it a few times on the last couple projects I've worked on.  Here are the relevant code snippets.

in mainwindow.h, inside your `MainWindow` class, under `public`

```
static QTextEdit * s_textEdit;
```

in mainwindow.cpp, outside of any function

```
QTextEdit * MainWindow::s_textEdit = 0;
```

in MainWindow constructor

```
s_textEdit = new QTextEdit;
// be sure to add the text edit into the GUI somewhere, 
// like in a layout or on a tab widget, or in a dock widget
```

in main.cpp, above the `main()`

```
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    if(MainWindow::s_textEdit == 0)
    {
        QByteArray localMsg = msg.toLocal8Bit();
        switch (type) {
        case QtDebugMsg:
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
            break;
        case QtWarningMsg:
            fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
            break;
        case QtCriticalMsg:
            fprintf(stderr, "Critical: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
            break;
        case QtFatalMsg:
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
            abort();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (type) {
        case QtDebugMsg:
        case QtWarningMsg:
        case QtCriticalMsg:
            // redundant check, could be removed, or the 
            // upper if statement could be removed
            if(MainWindow::s_textEdit != 0)
                MainWindow::s_textEdit->append(msg);
            break;
        case QtFatalMsg:
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

inside main() in main.cpp, before initializing `QApplication` instance.

```
qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageOutput);
```

Note: This works wonderfully for any single threaded application.  Once you start using `qDebug()` outside your GUI thread, you will crash.  You then need to create a `QueuedConnection` from any threaded function (anything not running on your GUI thread), to connect to your instance of `MainWindow::s_textEdit`, like so:

```
QObject::connect(otherThread, SIGNAL(debug(QString)),
                 s_textEdit, SLOT(append(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

If you end up using `QDockWidget`s and making use of the `QMenu`, there are some additional cool things that you can do.  The end result it a very user-friendly, easy-to-manage console window.

```
QMenu * menu;
menu = this->menuBar()->addMenu("About");
menu->setObjectName(menu->title());

// later on...

QDockWidget *dock;
dock = new QDockWidget("Console", this);
dock->setObjectName(dock->windowTitle());
dock->setWidget(s_textEdit);
s_textEdit->setReadOnly(true);
this->addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dock);
this->findChild<QMenu*>("About")->addAction(dock->toggleViewAction());
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to phyatts answer.
To make the thing thread-safe you can also create something of the following. That will resolve the issue for any thread of that application that may want to send its debug stream.

```
namespace Mainwindow_ {
class Emitter : public QObject 
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    Emitter(){};
    ~Emitter(){};
    signals:    
    void append_log(QString msg);
};
}
```

Similar to the `s_textEdit` create a static object of the above class.
In the header:

```
static QTextEdit * s_text_edit;
static Mainwindow_::Emitter s_emitter;
```

In the .cpp:

```
QTextEdit * MainWindow::s_text_edit = 0;
Mainwindow_::Emitter MainWindow::s_emitter;
```

in its constructor:

```
s_text_edit = new QTextEdit("Starting .. ");
connect(&s_emitter, SIGNAL(append_log(QString)), s_text_edit, SLOT(append(QString)));
```

You can call that `append_log` from inside the `myMessageOutput` with:

```
emit MainWindow::s_emitter.append_log(msg);
```

Please excuse the naming differences. I tested this in Qt version 5.7 and 5.9. If there is any caveats please let me know.

Comment: I posted this since the solution with 
QObject::connect(otherThread, SIGNAL(debug(QString)),
                 s_textEdit, SLOT(append(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
would not work for me.