# Deleting items from QT's QListWidget leading to undeletion/corruption of other entries

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistwidget, qt6

*Disclaimer : I am pretty new to UI and QT.*

I have UI that have QListWidget comprising of some numbers (1 to 5),  now I am trying to delete the item one by one..

**Problem** :
After deletion of all entries are done, I can still see some entries (specifically 2 & 4).

**Code:**

1. File : main.cpp 
   Here I have created one async thread that will call MainWindows::display function.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    static MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    std::thread([]{
        w.display();
    }).detach();

    a.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

2. File : mainwindow.cpp 
   Here display function is deleting the items.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void MainWindow::display()
{
    sleep(15);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        auto j = ui->listWidget->takeItem(i);
        delete j;
    }

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

3. File : mainwindow.UI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>180</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>256</width>
      <height>192</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>2</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>3</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>4</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>5</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>19</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Output:

[image]

Questions:

1. Why this is happening? am I doing something wrong?
2. If this leads to undeletion/corruption is there any other way to achieve it?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is not really related to Qt but has to do with arrays and loops in general.

Say, initially, I start with a list:

```
0. Apple
1. Orange
2. Jackfruit
```

I remove the item at index 0:

```
0. Orange
1. Jackfruit
```

Now in the loop, we do `i++`, and then remove the item at index 1.

```
0. Orange
```

Notice that we completely skipped `Orange` because it moved down as we incremented our index.

If you want to delete everything, you can use [`QListWidget::clear()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#clear) instead.

---

As for memory "corruption", the `delete j` is ok, since you need to manage the pointer yourself after calling [`takeItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#takeItem).

On a side note, I wouldn't mix `std::thread` with Qt ([see comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919039/stdthread-with-qt)).