# QStandardItemModel delete multiple rows without problem - python

Tags: python, qt

I'm coding a reddit bot and created a UI like this:

[image]

What I want to do is user selects an account from list, clicks the remove selected account and all checked accounts deleted from list. So here is my code:

```
def delete_selected_accounts(self):
    print(len(self.account_list))
    for i in range(self.model.rowCount()):

        if self.model.item(i).checkState() == Qt.Checked:
            self.model.removeRow(i)
            self.account_list.pop(i)
```

However, this code does not work as expected. When I removeRow from a model or pop from the account list, count of lists changes and I'm getting list out of range problem. What can I do to delete selected item without this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hehe, I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74534510/deleting-items-from-qts-qlistwidget-leading-to-undeletion-corruption-of-other-e/74534683#74534683) yesterday.

You're iterating over `N` rows (`N` being the original number of rows), but along the way, you remove some of the rows. The result? Eventually you'll try to access `self.model.item(N - 1)`, which would be out of range.

One way to solve this is to iterate from the back (from `N - 1` to `0`), so that deleted rows don't affect future rows.

```py
for i in range(self.model.rowCount())[::-1]:
    ...
```

Here, `[::-1]` tells `range` to generate a reverse range. You could write it out explicitly like so: `range(self.model.rowCount() - 1, -1, -1)`. But it looks a bit ugly.

Comment: This is actually a genious solution lol. Thanks for the help