# Emit signal to update UI from thread

Tags: c++, qt

I have defined a new slot in a class that inherits from QThread:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyThread(QString fileName);
    void run() override;

signals:
    void addNewItem(int row, int col, QString text);

private:
    QString fileName;
};
```

In the Dialog class I have defined slot that should get called when the above signal will be emitted. This slot updates widget on UI:

```
void Dialog::onAddNewItem(int row, int col, QString text)
{
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, col, new QTableWidgetItem(text));
}
```

In the constructor of the Dialog class I have created the working thread and connected signal to a slot:

```
worker = new MyThread(filePath);
worker->run();

connect(worker, &MyThread::addNewItem, this, &Dialog::onAddNewItem);
```

In the `run()` function I'm emitting the *addNewItem* signal but the *onAddNewItem* slot never gets called. Why is that?

Comment: plop..... change `worker->run();` to `worker->start();`

Comment: See examples in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/60753560/4149835

Comment: By calling `worker->run();` you are executing in the same thread as the GUI thread. And the `connect(worker, &MyThread::addNewItem, this, &Dialog::onAddNewItem);` happens after the run() has finished so don't expect to get your signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have connected signals and slots after the thread runs.

1. Replace `worker->run()` with `worker->start()`. The `start` member immediately calls `run` once the thread starts successfully.
2. Connect signals and slots as follows:

```
worker = new MyThread(filePath);
connect(worker, &MyThread::addNewItem, this, &Dialog::onAddNewItem);
worker->start();
```